# where is the product_uuid in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

I was reading this forum and it said you can find product_uuid in /sys/class/dmi.. etc.

I don't have a dmi folder in /sys/class.  I have a dma but not a dmi.

Using find a locate don't show it, and this is a Ubuntu system version 13.x

--updated--

here's what I get on login:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 13.10 (GNU/Linux 3.8.13.14 armv7l)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

65 packages can be updated.
47 updates are security updates.

Last login: Thu Mar 20 07:22:00 2014 from marketingsmini2
```

/sys/devices/virtual/dmi doesn't work either - doesn't exist

Comment: I’d always been using /sys/class/dmi. Seems /sys/devices/virtual/dmi works

Comment: actually neither of those work.  here are the contents of /sys/class:

backlight, bdi, block, bluetooth, bsg, dma, drm, dvb, extcon, firmware, gpio, graphics, hidraw, i2c-adapter, input, lcd, leds, mdio_bus, mem, misc, mmc_host, net, power_supply, rc, regulator, rtc, sound, spi_master, thermal, tty, uio, ump, vc, video4linux, vtconsole

Answer (score 2):

works for me.  Maybe you have the wrong name or what you have installed does not support this

```
jamie@jamie-Ideapad-Z570:~$ ls /sys/class/dmi/id/product_uuid 
/sys/class/dmi/id/product_uuid
jamie@jamie-Ideapad-Z570:~$ more /sys/class/dmi/id/product_uuid 
/sys/class/dmi/id/product_uuid: Permission denied
jamie@jamie-Ideapad-Z570:~$ sudo more /sys/class/dmi/id/product_uuid 
[sudo] password for jamie: 
40F34E10-8D7A-E111-9097-9EA4030C1E23
jamie@jamie-Ideapad-Z570:~$ uname -a
Linux jamie-Ideapad-Z570 3.2.0-59-generic #90-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 7 22:43:51 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: here's what I get on login:
`    Welcome to Ubuntu 13.10 (GNU/Linux 3.8.13.14 armv7l)

     * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
    
    65 packages can be updated.
    47 updates are security updates.
    
    Last login: Thu Mar 20 07:22:00 2014 from marketingsmini2`